# HTML tags are displayed in mail

Tags: php, html-email

I am trying to send a text by mail in php. The message is placed inside a HTML tag. While sending, the mail part works but the text I receive has HTML tags in it.

Here is the code for better understanding of my issue:

```
$car = "1223455667";
$to = "something@sample.com";
$subject = 'Test Mail';
$message = '<p>' . $car . '</p>';

$from = 'mymail@sample.com';

if(mail($to, $subject, $message )){
    echo 'success';
}else{
    echo 'Unable to send the email. Please try again.';
}
```

Output I receive in mail:

[image]

I expect the output like this: 1223455667

Comment: Did you send it as HTML mail? Did you view it as text mail? (You need to set a `Content-Type` header for HTML mails to be sent)

Comment: Yes I received it like <p>1223455667</p> @kerbholz

Comment: No. You sent a _text_ mail with HTML elements as body - which are displayed as regular text since you didn't specify the content-type for the mail to be HTML. The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) has an example on how to send HTML emails.

Comment: If you _don't_ want to see HTML elements in your text mail: just don't use them

Comment: I need to use a <a> tag there in mail @kerbholz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass Headers in your mail

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers )){
    echo 'success';
}else{
    echo 'Unable to send the email. Please try again.';
}
```